# Connecting to Oracle Database through C#?

Tags: c#, oracle, c#-4.0

I need to connect to a Oracle DB (external) through Visual Studio 2010. But I dont want to install Oracle on my machine. 
In my project I referenced: **System.Data.OracleClient**. But its not fulfilling the need. 
I have an **"Oracle SQL Developer IDE"** in which I run SQL queries against oracle db.

I have this code so far:

```
 private static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        String connString = "host= serverName;database=myDatabase;uid=userName;pwd=passWord";
        return connString;
    }

 private static void ConnectingToOracle()
    {
        string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
        using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection())
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            connection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("State: {0}", connection.State);
            Console.WriteLine("ConnectionString: {0}",
                              connection.ConnectionString);

            OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM myTableName";
            command.CommandText = sql;

            OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string myField = (string)reader["MYFIELD"];
                Console.WriteLine(myField);
            }
        }
    }
```

So far I read these blogs:

http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/tutorial/DBXETutorial/index.htm

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2009/07/18/connecting-to-oracle-from-visual-studio.aspx

So far I have not downloaded anything from Oracle. What steps should I take to make this happen?

Comment: have you tried with Oracle Data provider for .Net.

Comment: Do you mean this file: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

Comment: `its not fulfilling the need` - what do you mean by this?  What need is it not fulfilling?

Comment: have a look at this. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

Comment: The need to connect to Oracle DB.

Comment: @PrabhuMurthy: The file has Oracle 11g in it. Is there something else which is light?

Comment: i think you should probably look at oracle instant client.Its lighter but tricky to implement(though its my personal experience)http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html

Comment: Didn't Microsoft discontinue native Oracle support in the Framework like a long time ago? I'm thinking since like .NET 2.0?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

First off you need to download and install ODP from this site
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

After installation add a reference of the assembly **Oracle.DataAccess.dll**.

Your are good to go after this.

```
using System; 
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client; 

class OraTest
{ 
    OracleConnection con; 
    void Connect() 
    { 
        con = new OracleConnection(); 
        con.ConnectionString = "User Id=<username>;Password=<password>;Data Source=<datasource>"; 
        con.Open(); 
        Console.WriteLine("Connected to Oracle" + con.ServerVersion); 
    }

    void Close() 
    {
        con.Close(); 
        con.Dispose(); 
    } 

    static void Main() 
    { 
        OraTest ot= new OraTest(); 
        ot.Connect(); 
        ot.Close(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: There are two files: One is 55MB and the other is: 225MB. Which one should I download?

Comment: And it also says: 64-bit ODAC 11.2 Release 5 (11.2.0.3.20) Xcopy for Windows x64. What is Xcopy?

Comment: you can go for basic lite.http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html.the lite version weighs about 19mb

Comment: yes pal so much so that i reverted back my own implementation back to ODP :)

Comment: so what you suggest ..To install ODP.Net?

Comment: Which one should I download? The 225MB one? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

Comment: There is one another in Release 5 which is 55MB. Dont know what is that?

Comment: haven't tried the xcopy version,But i suspect it has to do with you installing it manually.Its the 225 that ive been using.

Comment: How should I regard the System.Data.OracleClient library?

Comment: Better to use the NuGet package

Comment: What does the data source string look like? I have a SID and an IP address to connect to. Is it some sort of combination of the two?

Answer (score 25):

You can use **[Oracle.ManagedDataAccess](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/)** NuGet package too (.NET >= 4.0, database >= 10g Release 2).

Comment: Note with the Nuget package - you don't have to install any other dependencies (like ODP). This is the easiest way to connect now.

Comment: @DavidMohundro Nuget package is usually the easiest way for everything :).

Comment: This works like a charm. How to connect to Oracle Forms 6? Running on .Net Framework 4.5+

Answer (score 25):

**Using Nuget**

1. Right click Project, select `Manage NuGet packages...`
2. Select the `Browse` tab, search for `Oracle` and install [`Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/)

[image: Oracle NuGet package]

3. In code use the following command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to automatically add the using directive).
4. Note the different DataSource string which in comparison to Java is
   different.

   ```
   // create connection
   OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();

   // create connection string using builder
   OracleConnectionStringBuilder ocsb = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder();
   ocsb.Password = "autumn117";
   ocsb.UserID = "john";
   ocsb.DataSource = "database.url:port/databasename";

   // connect
   con.ConnectionString = ocsb.ConnectionString;
   con.Open();
   Console.WriteLine("Connection established (" + con.ServerVersion + ")");
   ```

Comment: Use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core if using a .NET 2.x core app instead of a .NET 4.x app.

Answer (score 2):

Code examples above are correct but also need to take care of the version of the package. In case of package version not compatible code throws TimeOut exception. For dotnet core or dotnet 6 or above use below package

```
 <PackageReference Include="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core" Version="3.21.90" />
```

Another thing is about DataSource one can also provide data source in below format.

```
"(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = <HOSTNAME>) (PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = <DBNAME>)))"
```

Answer (score 1):

The next approach work to me with Visual Studio 2013 Update 4
1- From Solution Explorer right click on References then select add references
2- Assemblies > Framework > System.Data.OracleClient > OK
and after that you free to add using System.Data.OracleClient in your application and deal with database like you do with Sql Server database except changing the prefix from Sql to Oracle as in SqlCommand become OracleCommand for example to link to Oracle XE

```
OracleConnection oraConnection = new OracleConnection(@"Data Source=XE; User ID=system; Password=*myPass*");
public void Open()
{
if (oraConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
{
oraConnection.Open();
}
}
public void Close()
{
if (oraConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
oraConnection.Close();
}}
```

and to execute some command like INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE using stored procedure we can use the following method

```
public void ExecuteCMD(string storedProcedure, OracleParameter[] param)
{
OracleCommand oraCmd = new OracleCommand();
oraCmd,CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
oraCmd.CommandText = storedProcedure;
oraCmd.Connection = oraConnection;

if(param!=null)
{
oraCmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
}
try
{
oraCmd.ExecuteNoneQuery();
}
catch (Exception)
{
MessageBox.Show("Sorry We've got Unknown Error","Connection Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically in this case, **System.Data.OracleClient** need access to some of the oracle dll which are not part of .Net. Solutions:

- Install Oracle Client , and add bin location to Path environment varaible of windows
  OR
- Copy 
  oraociicus10.dll (Basic-Lite version) or aociei10.dll (Basic version),
  oci.dll, orannzsbb10.dll and oraocci10.dll from oracle client installable folder to bin folder of application so that application is able to find required dll