# Error in Database connection C# -> OracleDB

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I try to connect to an OracleDB from an c# project.

```
SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(
"Server=127.0.0.1:3306;Database=db1;User id=abc;Password=psw;");
```

While running the code an exeption is thrown:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll 
>   A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25
>   - Connection string is not valid)

I tried to connect with an local mysql db either and the same exeption is thrown.
I can connect to the server with the Oracle SQL developer tool.

Where is the Problem ?

Comment: `OracleDB` using SqlConnection ???. You know `SqlConnection` is for `SQL Server`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a SqlConnection (SQL Server) to connect to an Oracle database. See this answer on how to connect to an Oracle database:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12568350/2382032

As Flindeberg points out, here is the NuGet link:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/odp.net.managed/

Comment: Eh, no, that is the unmanaged driver, don't use that one. Since about a year back they have a managed driver (ie .NET).

Comment: The answer I link to has a link to the same place as your answer, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html. Thanks though, I will update my answer with the nuget link. I wish they had NuGet back in the day when I had to connect to Oracel!

Comment: Now I can connect to the server but the login fails. Do I have to surround the pasword with special chars or does it work like this:
"User ID=username;Password=asd;....."?

Comment: Every example I see here does not surround it with quotes: http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

Answer (score 1):

You are using `SqlConnection` class. This class is used to connect to Microsoft's `SQL Server` database.

Since the database you're making use of is Oracle's database, you'll need a 'Oracle' specific connection class.

You *can make* use of `OracleDBConnection` class though this is ***not advisable as it has been deprecated***.

Instead, you can make use of **[ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html)** which is provided & supported by Oracle.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Note this method of connecting has been depreciated: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7.aspx

Comment: System.Data.oracleClient has been deprecated

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I had forgotten it had been deprecated. Have edited my answer accordingly!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the connector for MS SQL server, don't do that. The only driver you should use for the [Oracle Managed ODP.NET driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/odp.net.managed/) which you can get at NuGet. [Documentation is available here.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html)

Make sure to use the managed driver, and not the unmanaged one.

Example of using it:

```
var connection = new OracleConnection(str);
using (var command = new OracleCommand(commandStr, connection))
{
   // do stuff with command
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using ODP.Net Driver from NuGet. 
Follow the instruction here:
[Connect to oracle from c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641951/connect-to-oracle-from-c-sharp/42709516#42709516)