# Connect to oracle from c#

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to connect Oracle 11g from C#. I have followed [this link], defined the connection allias like this:

```
moviess =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = xe)
    )
  )
```

When trying to connect using server explorer in Visual studio it gives me the following error :
[image]

Here is the installation directory of the Oracle Developer Tool for Visual Studio.
[image]

Where am I going wrong ? Kindly assist me.

Comment: Where did you put the connection identifier? I think C# by default has some trouble finding TNSNames.ora, unless you tell it where it is, or set the connection string without using TNSNames.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set proper path to TNSNAMES file in C# application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618512/how-to-set-proper-path-to-tnsnames-file-in-c-sharp-application)

Comment: Did you install the visual studio stuff from Oracle? I normally have more options and things to fill out.. not sure...

Comment: show your connection string after removing password etc. Refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820440/oracle-connection-string-without-tnsnames-ora-file

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

`ORA-12154: TNS: Could not resolve the connect identifier specified`

This is the cause:

> https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14219/net12150.htm
>
> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
>
> Cause: A connection to a database or other service was requested using a connect identifier, and the connect identifier specified could
>   not be resolved into a connect descriptor using one of the naming
>   methods configured.
>
> For example, if the type of connect identifier
>   used was a net service name then the net service name could not be
>   found in a naming method repository, or the repository could not be
>   located or reached.
>
> ```
> Action:
>
> - If you are using local naming (TNSNAMES.ORA file):
>
> - Make sure that "TNSNAMES" is listed as one of the values of the NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH parameter in the Oracle Net profile (SQLNET.ORA)
>
> - Verify that a TNSNAMES.ORA file exists and is in the proper directory and is accessible.
>
> - Check that the net service name used as the connect identifier exists in the TNSNAMES.ORA file.
> ```

Q: Is Oracle 11g actually installed on your local PC?  If not, you cannot use "localhost".  You must also install the Oracle client.

Relevant links:

- [Connecting to Oracle Database through C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568100/connecting-to-oracle-database-through-c)
- [Getting Started with Oracle Data Provider for .Net](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/dotnet/getstarted-c/getstarted_c_otn.htm)
- [Connecting to an Oracle Datasource Using ADO.Net](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/featConnecting.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Oracle ODP.Net Driver** from NuGet.

You can try these:

1. Right-click on *References* and hit *Manage NuGet packages*.
2. Select **Official Oracle ODP.Net, Managed Driver**

[image]

3. Reference "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
4. Invoke the actual connection.

**Here's the sample code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

namespace SampleOracle
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = "User Id=<username>;Password=<password>;Data Source=<data source>"; //Data Source Format -> //IP_HOST:PORT/SERVICE_NAME e.g. //127.0.0.1:1521/Service_Name
            connection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to Oracle" + connection.ServerVersion);           
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample output:**

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To reach your `Add Connection` window, you must have gone through this window first, right?

[image]

The message is pretty clear.  The provider you are trying to use is deprecated and doesn't support Oracle 11.

As recommended, consider downloading and installing [Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index.html) instead.

**EDIT:** I completely forgot to mention this very important tidbit for when you do get this working: Do ***not*** use `sys` to connect to the Oracle database for your development.  The `sys` user is very special and should only be used when absolutely necessary.  Instead, create a separate user, and use that for your development.

Comment: I have installed Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio. What do I do next? How will Visual Studio know that its installed and from where do I get the connection string for oracle?