# Method to query data from Oracle database in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, database-connection

Currently I'm using the following method to get data from Oracle database and return it to `DataTable`:

```
private static DataTable OraSelect(string cmdString)
{
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbconnection"];
    OracleConnection oraCon = new OracleConnection(conString);
    OracleCommand oraCmd = new OracleCommand(cmdString, oraCon);
    OracleDataAdapter oraDA = new OracleDataAdapter(oraCmd.CommandText, oraCon);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    oraCon.Open();
    oraDA.Fill(dt);
    oraCon.Close();
    return dt;
}
```

Visual Studio displays the following warning: "OracleConnection has been deprecated."

I think that's not the best way to do this. Could you give me some examples about how to get data from an Oracle database with a better method?

Comment: Have you tried searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [MSDN Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) as it clearly says in the class definiton

```
[ObsoleteAttribute("OracleConnection has been deprecated. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=144260", 
    false)]
public sealed class OracleConnection : DbConnection, ICloneable
```

Follow the link mentioned in attribute constructor parameter ([Oracle and ADO.NET](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=144260))

You should rather use the specific [Data provider from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html)

An Example: [Connecting to Oracle Database through C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568100/connecting-to-oracle-database-through-c)