# How to configure an oracle database in apache ignite .NET

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, ignite

I'm trying to configure the write-through and read-through properties of apache Ignite with an Oracle database. I searched in many places like the Ignite oficial documentation, also in the ignite examples on GitHub,
but there isn't much information or examples coded in C# that is the lenguaje in which I'm developing my app.

What I want is to retrieve from a persistent store (in this case an Oracle database),  an specific data in the cache (Ignite) that is not already loaded. In a similar way, I need all my changes on the cache to be reflected on the database.

I tied to create and spring.xml with the configuration of the database (ip, port, username, pass, database), but I can't make it work if that is the way it should be done.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Implement `ICacheStore` interface (or inherit `CacheStoreAdapter` helper class)

```
public class OracleStore : CacheStoreAdapter
{
    public override object Load(object key)
    {
        using (var con = new OracleConnection
        {
            ConnectionString = "User Id=<username>;Password=<password>;Data Source=<datasource>"
        })
        {
            con.Open();

            var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID=@id";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OracleType.Int32);
            cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = key;

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // Read data, return as object
            }
        }
    }

    public override void Write(object key, object val)
    {
        oracleDb.UpdateRow(key, val);
    }

    public override void Delete(object key)
    {
        oracleDb.DeleteRow(key);
    }
}
```

2) Implement store factory:

```
public class OracleStoreFactory : IFactory<OracleStore>
{
    public OracleStore CreateInstance()
    {
        return new OracleStore();
    }
}
```

3) Configure cache to use store:

```
using (var ignite = Ignition.Start())
{
    var cacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration
    {
        ReadThrough = true,
        WriteThrough = true,
        KeepBinaryInStore = false,  // Depends on your case
        CacheStoreFactory = new OracleStoreFactory()
    };

    var cache = ignite.CreateCache<int, MyClass>(cacheCfg);

    cache.Get(1);  // OracleStore.Load is called.
}
```

---

Documentation for Ignite.NET (in C#): https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/persistent-store

C# examples are available in a full download package: https://ignite.apache.org/download.cgi#binaries (click apache-ignite-fabric-1.9.0-bin.zip, download, unzip, open platforms\dotnet\examples\Apache.Ignite.Examples.sln)

Blog post explaining cache store implementation in C#:
https://ptupitsyn.github.io/Entity-Framework-Cache-Store/

Working with Oracle DB in .NET: [Connecting to Oracle Database through C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568100/connecting-to-oracle-database-through-c)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I don't understand where you set the connection parameters for the oracle database, I mean, where you put the url, username and password. Can you explain me that part? thanks!

Comment: I've added some more details, though it is off the topic of Ignite.NET. See this question for Oracle details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568100/connecting-to-oracle-database-through-c

Comment: Thanks! I'll try with that.