# ORA-28040 exception on connecting to external db

Tags: c#, oracle12c

I know the problem with `ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol`
was discussed here plenty of times, but from I can gather all of the provided solutions (like `sqlnet.ora` edition or replacing `ojdbc14.jar` with another one) were to made on the server side.

Unfortunately I am not permitted to interfere with the server in any way.

I had some nice simple tool to read records from different DBs and compare them. Connecting to DB is done by:

```
using System.Data.OracleClient;
...
    using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(conString))
    {
       connection.Open();
       ...
    }
```

Now it throws aforementioned exception.
I will appreciate any way to replace this code with something which will actually connect to Oracle 12c.

I tried "dotConnect for Oracle 9.4 Express" from Devart but it gave the same error.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568100/connecting-to-oracle-database-through-c).

Instaling `Oracle Data Provider for .NET` from [ODAC 12.2c Release 1 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (12.2.0.1.0)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html) did the trick.

And remember about this:

> "After installation add a reference of the assembly
>   Oracle.DataAccess.dll."